# How to add an "Item" object to an Object ArrayList in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the following class

```
class Item {
    var name: String = ""

    constructor(n: String) {
        name = n
    }

}
```

On my main activity I have declared this:

```
var list: ArrayList<Object> = ArrayList<Object>()
```

When I try to do this

```
list.add(Item("Hey friend"))
```

The compiler complains about type mismatch (Object -> Item) which is obviously true but since Item is also an Object, shouldn't this be fine? I'm pretty sure you can do this in Java, whats the alternative?

I need the list to be of type object because I have to store different stuff in there, so changing it is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supertype of all types in Kotlin is [`Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/), not `Object`.

Other things you can improve in `var list: ArrayList<Object> = ArrayList<Object>()`:

- make it a `val` because immutability is preferred
- If you need an explicit type declaration, use the interface `List<Any`
- use Kotlin's collection builders `listOf()`

```
val items: List<Any> = listOf()`
```

Also, the class definition can be reduced to

```
class Item(val name: String) //could even be a data class
```

Comment: One question regarding this, Any is not equivalent to Object right? So if I have a java class with a method that receives a list of type Object, would it work if I feed it a list of type Any?

Comment: It is being mapped to Object so yes, you should replace Java Object with Any (read here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types)